# Web Applications (http): Don't get how token based authentication is secure

Tags: tls, authentication, http

See something like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826293/restful-authentication-via-spring/10864088#comment21706215_10864088

Or more specific:

[Token-based authentication - Securing the token](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19676/token-based-authentication-securing-the-token)

My question now is:

Man in the middle can just read the token and use it in is own request. I mean he doesn't need to know what the token actually means or anything, he can just use it. What am I missing?
I don't see how this is any better than having a session cookie in terms of security?

So as far as I can tell, the only thing you can actually do is to always use ssl and then you can just drop the whole token thing and use basic auth for every request?

The only advantage of the token I see is that you don't need to use basic auth and get more control, like an actual log out and nicer login form and such (at the cost of higher complexity).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Token-based authentication is not about securing the communication against third party attackers. It is to secure *the server* against *the client himself*.

For proper security you need SSL anyway. Without SSL, imagine an **active** attacker, e.g. that funny-looking bearded geek sitting two tables from you in the same restaurant -- you don't know it, but he has a [fake WiFi access point](http://hakshop.myshopify.com/products/wifi-pineapple) in his backpack, and he is currently intercepting your Internet traffic, which you *believe* to go through the restaurant "free WiFi". That guy can hijack your communications at any point. He sees what you send to Web sites and what you receive from these sites, and he can alter both kinds of data at will. When he chuckles and almost gags on his milk-shake, that's because he is reading your emails.

To defeat active attackers, you need something which protects the data confidentiality and integrity, and makes sure that you talk to the right server, not to the [Bearded-Geek-in-the-Middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). And that "something" is [SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure).

With SSL, you can indeed just use [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-2). This will work... provided that you *want* to use HTTP Basic Authentication, because that authentication is handled by the Web browser, with its own popup, which can be ugly. For instance, it may look like this:

[image: Firefox login popup]

Most Web designers are appalled at the sheer practicality and minimalism of this popup, which is reminiscent of the glorious architectural experiments from the Stalin era. Therefore, almost nobody does that. Instead, Web sites implement their own "login page", in pure HTML, and therefore cannot benefit from the inherent support of Basic Authentication by the browser. They must use a cookie, i.e. the "authentication token" which we are talking about.

Moreover, user authentication is not necessarily based on a login and a password. Some sites do funkier things, including delegating authentication to another server, using the [OAuth protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth). This very site, `security.stackexchange.com`, does that. This again calls for some storage of data on the client browser, data which is *not* a login and password.

Once you begin to store data on the client browser, you may envision to store data that should remain opaque for the user himself (should he be inquisitive enough to have a look at his cookies), and which resists modifications from the user (depending on the data and what it's used for). This calls for, respectively, **encryption** and **checked integrity**. That kind of "securing" is all about storing things in the client system but without trusting the client system.

Comment: ok thanks. So in other words a lot of sites are basically insecure (like the average php-based forums) because the bearded guy could easily steal the session cookie.

Comment: Awesome response, clarifies the matter in a very accurate way, with some cynicism thrown in which makes it even more indulging to read.